# Nested enum entry

Tags: android, kotlin

I've written a code that displays Eu consent form in my app (initially in java than copied in my kotlin project), in java works fine, but in kotlin gives me "Nested enum entry 'PERSONALIZED' accessed via instance reference" and "Nested enum entry 'NON_PERSONALIZED' accessed via instance reference" `val unit = if (consentStatus == consentStatus.PERSONALIZED || consentStatus == consentStatus.NON_PERSONALIZED)`
I've searched in the web, but haven't find any solution

```
val consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(applicationContext)
        val publisherIds = arrayOf("pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(publisherIds, object : ConsentInfoUpdateListener {
            override fun onConsentInfoUpdated(consentStatus: ConsentStatus) {
                // User's consent status successfully updated.
                val inEEA = ConsentInformation.getInstance(applicationContext).isRequestLocationInEeaOrUnknown

                if (inEEA) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@FramesActivity, consentStatus.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    val unit = if (consentStatus == consentStatus.PERSONALIZED || consentStatus == consentStatus.NON_PERSONALIZED) {
                        val extras = Bundle()
                        extras.putString("npa", "1")

                        val request = AdRequest.Builder()
                                .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter::class.java, extras)
                                .build()
                    } else {
                        var privacyUrl: URL? = null
                        try {
                            // TODO: Replace with your app's privacy policy URL.
                            privacyUrl = URL("https://www.your.com/privacyurl")
                        } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                            // Handle error.
                        }

                        form = ConsentForm.Builder(this@FramesActivity, privacyUrl)
                                .withListener(object : ConsentFormListener() {
                                    override fun onConsentFormLoaded() {
                                        // Consent form loaded successfully.
                                        form?.show()
                                    }

                                    override fun onConsentFormOpened() {
                                        // Consent form was displayed.
                                    }

                                    override fun onConsentFormClosed(
                                            consentStatus: ConsentStatus?, userPrefersAdFree: Boolean?) {
                                        // Consent form was closed.
                                        val extras = Bundle()
                                        extras.putString("npa", "1")

                                        val request = AdRequest.Builder()
                                                .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter::class.java, extras)
                                                .build()
                                    }

                                    override fun onConsentFormError(errorDescription: String?) {
                                        // Consent form error.
                                    }
                                })
                                .withPersonalizedAdsOption()
                                .withNonPersonalizedAdsOption()
                                // .withAdFreeOption()
                                .build()
                        form?.load()

                    }
                } else {
                    //  Toast.makeText(StickerPackListActivity.this, "Not In EEA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            override fun onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo(errorDescription: String) {
                // User's consent status failed to update.
                //  Toast.makeText(StickerPackListActivity.this, errorDescription, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line appears to be wrong:

```
val unit = if (consentStatus == consentStatus.PERSONALIZED || consentStatus == consentStatus.NON_PERSONALIZED) {
```

If `ConsentStatus` is an Enum, what you are probably looking for is this, referencing **ConsentStatus** and **not** the variable **consentStatus**:

```
val unit = if (consentStatus == ConsentStatus.PERSONALIZED || consentStatus == ConsentStatus.NON_PERSONALIZED) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the static class name like this: `ClassName.ENUM` that should take care of your error.

You don't have to instantiate your enum classes to use them,  in your case `consentStatus == ConsentStatus.PERSONALIZED`